# Problems with std::chrono : Reset a time

Tags: c++

Hello I have a problem with std::chrono I do the insert of include. I try to reset a time to zero with a function Start.

my function into .cpp

```
void MyTimer::Start(){ std::chrono::duration::zero;}
```

my.hh have a Singleton and my function

```
public :
    static MyTime& GetInstance;
 private:
    static MyTime t_getinstance;
    MyTime& operator = 'const MyTime&){}
    MyTime (const MyTime&){}
    void Start();
```

Do I need to include another library to use chrono ? And if I want to reset my time the std:chrono:duration::zero is a good idea? Because I don't understand very well this library.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/zero

Comment: Please don't rewrite code into the question, or you will add unrelated problems. Instead try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: A video tutorial is an easy way to get started with `<chrono>`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset time back to the big-bang?  no.

The effort is simply to compute the difference between two time-points. And the simple idea starts with now().

```
#include <chrono>
// 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; 
typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds           MS_t;    
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds            NS_t;    
using   namespace std::chrono_literals; // suffixes: 100ms, 2s, 30us
```

And use for time duration measurement like the following:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();  // time point 1

   int retVal = 0;
   {
      T514_t   test514;
      retVal = test514.exec();  // do interesting stuff
   }

   auto  duration_us =  
     std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);
  // time points ------------------  -------2------- - ----1---

   // after cast for duration extract------vvvvvvv 
   std::cout << "  FINI   " << duration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;
   return(static_cast<int>(errStr.size()));
}
```

Comment: Time_t does not imply time unit.   start_us simply reminds the reader of what units I wish to display for this effort.  this same difference between time point 1 and 2 can also be duration_cast to milliseconds (MS_t), or nanoseconds (NS_t).

Answer (score 1):

`std::chrono` is not a timer; you can't set it to zero. The function `zero()` simply returns a **value** of 0. To get elapsed time, first get the current time, then do whatever you need to do, and get the current time again. Subtract the starting time from the ending time. There's an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).